# Can't run application under win 64 on different machine

Tags: win64

I have been writnig my app in MS VC++ 2008.

Under win32 my application works fine on machines without VC++,
but version compiled as 64bit doesn't.

I am having this error:

```
"Application has failed to start because application configuration is incorrect"
```

I am compiling as Release, target platform is: x64 and Runtime library is selected as Multi-threaded (/MT).

I don't wan't user to install any additional VC Redist, I just want to static link every needed library into my app.

Maybe some kind of bug in VC ? (got VC SP1)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a partial solution, I am using additional FreeImage.lib static lib, when I unlinked it, the program run ok in 64bit application. Its strange, because I compiled FreeImage lib as 64 bit, I will be now checking this issue.

Comment: Perhaps the freeimage lib dynamically links to other libraries.

Comment: I compiled FreeImage.lib as Release, target platform is: x64 and Runtime library is selected as Multi-threaded (/MT), so I think this lib file should be standalone.

Comment: @Mateusz Please, when have more information update your question, don't post it as an answer, Thanks.